# Multiple Insert Statement in a Single Procedure - Is it good or bad?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I am making some project where i have to insert multiple records in different different table. So, i have created a single procedure and write down my all insert statements in a single procedure.
So, Is it good approach or not?

> Below is example

```
Create proc dbo.InsCustomer
as
begin

insert a
select 1

insert b
select 1

insert c
select 1

insert d
select 1

End
```

Comment: **So, Is it good approach or not? ** Yes it is!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a good idea. Any block of SQL code that belongs together can/should be executed on the database server in on go. This avoids multiple connections to the server from your application.

It also makes it easier to use a transaction around all the various statements.